Grouping and sorting on spark structured streaming
I have a usecase where I have streaming dataset like mobile number ,starttime and call duration.
I need to do group by on mobile number and sort the group based on starttime and filter out the calls where the sum(starttime + duration) greater than the next sum ( starttime+duration)
I tried Window.partitionby("mobilenumber").orderby("starttime")
But later figured it out that it will not work for streaming datasets

This is not possible standardly, unless complete mode is used. More specifically:
Sorting operations are supported on streaming Datasets only after an aggregation and in Complete Output Mode.

The basic tenet of Spark Structured Streaming is that a query should
return the same answer in streaming or batch mode. We support sorting
in complete mode because we have all the data and can sort it
correctly and return the full answer. In update or append mode,
sorting would only return a correct answer if we could promise that
records that sort lower are going to arrive later (and we can't).
Therefore, it is disallowed.

Write to a table or HDFS and then to a DB that has materialized views that can assist in incremental build aspects. This in preference to UDAF which works - until you change some of the stateful operations in a way that you lose all that stateful data. With former approach you still have that data - persisted. See the docs. That database could be Delta table these days.

I tried to create a udaf and passing the starttime and duration columns, collect all of them into arraylist , then sort that list and comparing adjacent indexes , but here the problem is aggregate functions returns a single value (but my conditions on the dataset would return more values ) and if my stream gets new data will the whole process be re-computed , and is this the right way to do sort ?

No. Not with collect. Just not a supported approach.

Well, not 100% correct what I state. UDAF not for pyspark and on restart of stream?

This in preference to UDAF which works - until you change some of the stateful operations in a way that you lose all that stateful data. With former approach you still have that data - persisted. See the docs. Updated answer.

Yes , I tried with udaf , but every time a new file or data is been added to the data stream need to sort the whole data where performance will go down
